# Problems with a node js module for the js-tiktoken/lite identifier

Tags: node.js, widget, chatbot, openai-api, langchain-js

I'm creating a chatbot as a widget in html and js and using node.js server as part and the various files to import are all in cdn.
When I launch the page the widget all works, but when I enter the question in the console it appears:

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: The identifier “js-tiktoken/lite” is a “bare” identifier, but was not remapped to any module. Relative module identifiers must begin with “./”, “../” or “/”."

But it's all external and I repeat in cdn, so I can't command anything, here's the code I'm interested in, can you help me?

Code:

```
import { TextLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/langchain@0.0.144/dist/document_loaders/fs/text.js';
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/langchain@0.0.144/dist/text_splitter.js';
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/langchain@0.0.144/dist/embeddings/openai.js';
import { MemoryVectorStore } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/langchain@0.0.144/dist/vectorstores/memory.js';
import { RetrievalQAChain } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/langchain@0.0.144/dist/chains/index.js';
import { ChatOpenAI } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/langchain@0.0.144/dist/chat_models/openai.js';

export async function chiedi(domanda){
  domanda="di che colore è il cielo";

 //CARICO I DATI
 const loader = new TextLoader("dati/data.txt");
 const data = await loader.load();

 //FRAMMENTA I DATI
 const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
   chunkSize: 500,
   chunkOverlap: 0,
 });
 const splitDocs = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(data);

 //CONSERVA I DATI IN UN VETTORE
 const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings();
 const vectorStore = await MemoryVectorStore.fromDocuments(splitDocs, embeddings);
 const relevantDocs = await vectorStore.similaritySearch("What is task decomposition?");
 console.log(relevantDocs.length);

 //AVVIA L'INTELLIGENZA ARTIFICIALE
 const model = new ChatOpenAI({ modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo", openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY, },);
 const chain = RetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(model, vectorStore.asRetriever());

 const risposta = await chain.call({
  query: domanda,
});


console.log(domanda);

}
```

Thanks

It should give me the question in the console that is placed in the variable by default, but nothing.
because it should then respond what it finds in the text file that acts as the database for the responses.